# Add IR LEDs to camera module

Tags: camera

I need the camera to work when it's dark so I need to include IR LEDs. Unfortunately the Raspberry Pi cameras that come with IR flood lights all come in the style which has 1 big IR flood light on each side. Unfortunately we've noticed that these are really unstable.

We want to transition to the type where you have multiple small IR lights in a ring structure around the camera. Is it possible buy one of these IR LED rings and connect it? If so, how would I go about that?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific please - e.g. are you looking to power it through the CSI port (which from the [schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3bplus_1p0_reduced.pdf) is just 3.3V, with enough current for 2 "[3W](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/130895/29454)" [LEDs](https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/camera/camera-boards/raspberry-pi-night-vision-camera), presumably through the screw connectors) - instead of just glueing some IR leds connected to another power source? Also, how are they unstable (may just be bad connection).

Answer (score 2):

This might work: [Cyntek IR LED Light Ring Board for Raspberry Pi](http://cpc.farnell.com/cyntech/lisiparoiir-01/rpi-ir-board-for-pi-camera/dp/SC13919)

> [image]

From the overview:

> The LISIPAROI is an add-on for the Raspberry Pi camera module and has
>   been designed to provide additional illumination when taking pictures
>   or recording video. It also features extra mounting points which is
>   perfect for using custom mounts or even a gooseneck holder. This
>   version features IR LEDs, suited for low/zero light with the PiNoir
>   module.
>
> - 12 IR LEDs
> - Ideal for security or low light applications
> - LED wavelength of 940nm